# ¿Como definir controllers y modelos en subcarpetas y usarlos en un proyecto con patron MVC PHP?

Tags: php, mvc

Hola tengo una duda que no se como hacerlo. Tengo un pequeño proyecto MVC donde la estructura es la siguiente:

- Controllers

  - IndexController.php
  - Nueva_Carpeta

    - NuevaCarpetaController.php
- Models

  - Index.php
  - Nueva_Carpeta_model

    - NuevaCarpeta.php
- Views

  - index.php
  - Nueva_Carpeta_Vista

    - vista_nueva_carpeta

Lo que intento es en esas subcarpetas crear otros controllers y poder usarlos. Cuando el controller se encuentra en la raiz simplemente uso esto

```
<?php

class IndexController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        //carga el contructor de la clase heredada
        parent::__construct();

    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['page_tag'] = "home";
        $data['page_title'] = "Pagina de inicio";
        $data['page_name'] = "Inicio";
        $this->view->getView("Login",$this, "login", $data);
    }
    
}
```

asi que si entro por la url como `misitio/micontroller/mimetodo` lo hago sin problemas pero ahora como haria para entrar a mi controller que se encuentra en la subcarpeta Nueva_Carpeta no entiendo bien como se podria hacer esto el index donde inicio todo es:

```
<?php


$url = $_GET["url"] ?? "Index/index";
$arrayUrl = explode("/", $url);
$controller = $arrayUrl[0] ?? "";
$method = $arrayUrl[1] ?? "";
$params = $arrayUrl[2] ?? "";

spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    // Verificar si existe el archivo
    if (file_exists("Core/App/" . $class . ".php")) {
        require_once("Core/App/" . $class . ".php");
    }
});

//capturar las rutas del controlador

$controllerClassName = $controller . "Controller";
$dirController = "Controllers/" . $controllerClassName . ".php";

//llamar al controlador errores

require_once "Controllers/ErrorController.php";
$error = new ErrorController();

// Verificar si el archivo del controlador existe
if (!file_exists($dirController)) {
    $error->errorPage($url);
    return;
}

//si existe requeririlo e instanciarlo para llamarlo con sus metodos y parametros si hubieran

require_once $dirController;
$controllerInstance = new $controllerClassName();

// Verificar si se proporcionó un método y si existe en el controlador si no usa el metodo index por defecto
$method = $method ?: 'index';

if (method_exists($controllerInstance, $method)) {
    // Verificar si se proporcionaron parámetros
    if (isset($params)) {

        $controllerInstance->{$method}($params);
    } else {
        // Llamar al método del controlador
        $controllerInstance->{$method}();
    }
} else {
    // Mostrar página de error
    $error->errorPage($url);
}
```